# npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I try to set up my react app, I got a error as shown below
Here are the Error i got when I run npx create-react-app react-app

any help please!

```
PS C:\Users\pc\Documents\ReactApps\react-app> npx create-react-app react-app
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxx.xxx.xxx.4
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-22T00_17_29_902Z-debug-0.log
```

I've tried a lot of commands but they are still useless, and I don't know how to figure it out

before I had some problems similar to this in my react project and I couldn't find a solution so I deleted all the folders, and now here are the problems

Comment: As the error describes this is an actual issue with your network. Are you behind a corporate firewall, or is this a home broadband connection? What happens if you hit http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app  in your browser, do you see JSON output?

Comment: When you use create-react-app it downloads packages from npm and for that it require better network connection.

Comment: it's okay colleagues it works, thank u